# How to prove all epics are retractions?

Tags: category-theory

In sets how to prove all epics are retractions? I am almost through but I just can't seem to make it a neat clear proof.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_(category_theory)) is a relevant wiki page that says all I'm about to say, more or less.

In $\textbf{Set}$ you have probably already learned that epics and surjections are the same thing. To show that each epic in $\textbf{Set}$ is split(i.e. has a right inverse) requires the Axiom of Choice, because it states that every surjection between sets has a section, i.e. a right inverse. Thus it follows that each epic is a left inverse to some other map, i.e. it is a retraction.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should make a small disclaimer that what is true here in $\textbf{Set}$ is not true in general. In the category $\textbf{Ab}$ of abelian groups there are definitely epics which are not split.

Comment: Who said we were talking about Set?

Comment: OP said "In sets", which I take to mean epics within $\textbf{Set}$. Obviously, not all epics in any category are split and therefore not retractions, unless the category satisfies the axiom of choice.

Comment: Wow sorry about that, I could have sworn it didn't mention Sets when I looked.